# How to exclude one column from data.table OR convert to data.table to MTS

Tags: r, data.table, zoo

When using `data.table` is it possible to return all the columns except one, like in `data.frame`?

If the answer is no, does anyone have an elegant way to transform a multiple time series `data.table` to a `zoo` or other time series object?

Consider the following example:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

## DEFINE DATA
set.seed(1)
dt = data.table(
    mydates = as.Date("2012-01-01") + 1:9, 
    value1 = sort(rpois(9, 6)),
    value2 = sort(rpois(9, 6)),
    value3 = sort(rpois(9, 6)),
    value4 = sort(rpois(9, 6)),
    value5 = sort(rpois(9, 6)))

## CONVERT TO DATA FRAME
df = as.data.frame(dt)

## CONVERT TO ZOO
zooObj = zoo(df[,-1], df$mydates)

## EXAMPLE OF DESIRED RESULTS
plot(zooObj, col=1:ncol(zooObj))
```

How would I do that without `df = as.data.frame(dt)`?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try `with=FALSE` :

```
dt[,-1,with=FALSE]
```

---

As an aside, feature request #416 is related :

[Add *not join* `DT[-J(...)]`, and *not columns* `DT[,-"colC",with=FALSE]`.](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/416)

Comment: As of version 1.8.3, this works: `dt[, !"mydates", with=FALSE]`

Comment: @ChristopherBrown Thanks for your [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6097805). Can't see why it was rejected by reviewers so I applied it.

Comment: @GSee, could you make that a full answer? It's the best answer now!

Comment: `dt[, !"mydates"]` without the `with=` now works as well

Comment: That's confusing it works for: `dt[, !"mydates"] `, but `col <-"mydates"` and then: dt[, !col] ` does not work, you need the `with`, for example this works: `dt[, !col, with=F]`

Comment: @DavidLeal, that's expected.  The `with=FALSE` only has an effect on variables named in the expression.  Using a literal `"mydates"` string, there's no variable, so it has no effect.  Using a variable means it now has to be told how to resolve that variable, either from the column names or ambient variables in scope.

Comment: This answer from 2012 needs an update now that `with=FALSE` isn't needed.

Answer (score 5):

The previous answer works, but here is the answer with the updated methods:

```
## CONVERT TO ZOO

#### old method
zooObj = zoo(x=dt[,-1,with=FALSE], order.by=dt$mydates)

#### alternatives
zooObj = zoo(x=dt[,!'mydates'], order.by=dt$mydates)
zooObj = zoo(x=dt[,-'mydates'], order.by=dt$mydates)

#### and if column name is a variable
myvar = 'mydates'
zooObj = zoo(x=dt[,!..myvar], order.by=dt[[myvar]])
zooObj = zoo(x=dt[,-..myvar], order.by=dt[[myvar]])
```

As an extension, if you wanted to remove more than one column from the `data.table`, try one of the following:

```
dt[,-c('value1', ..myvar)]
dt[, .SD, .SDcols = !c('value1', (myvar))]
```